# Self-location estimation from three landmarks under conditions where distance cannot be measured

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, parameter-estimation

There are all different points $O_1, O_2,$ and $O_3$ with known global coordinates in 3-dimensional space. Let $F, R, U$ be the $x, y, z$ basis vectors of the local coordinate system of point $P$ with unknown position and orientation in the global coordinate system.
$(x_k, y_k, z_k)$ are given one set for each $O_k$, and satisfy the following equation.

$$\text{normalize}(P - O_k) = \text{normalize}(F×x_k +  R×y_k + U×z_k) \;\text{for}\; O_1 \;\text{to}\; O_3(O_k)$$
Normalize is to set the vector magnitude to 1.
I would like to find the global coordinates of $P$ and the orientation of $P$ (quaternion or Euler angle) numerically, what algorithm should I use to find them?

The motivation for solving this problem is to find a way for a motionless particle-like swarm robot filling space to spontaneously acquire global coordinates and perform coordinate mapping as a whole.

Most of the particles initially do not know their global coordinates, but a very small number of particles (in this case, three points) are given their global coordinates from an external source that can observe the whole. In this situation, that reference particle robot emits its own global coordinate data as a one-dimensional digital signal in the form of electromagnetic waves to its surroundings. Other particle robots $P$ can interpret the direction of that transmitted electromagnetic wave and the coordinate data. This transmits the coordinates $O_k$ to particle P, which can then know the direction vector $(x_k, y_k, z_k)$ that the $O_k$ signal has traveled in its own local coordinate system.　Since each particle cannot spontaneously align its orientation and particle $P$ itself does not know its orientation in the global coordinate system, particle $P$ can only know the $O_kP$ vector in its local coordinates. What I want to achieve here is to infer P's own global coordinates using only the information $(O_k, (x_k, y_k, z_k)) (k=1,2,3)$ that particle $P$ can know.

Comment: 1. Please state the problem more clearly.  I don't know what is meant by "are given one set for each..."  Please define all notation. I don't know what normalize() refers to.  It is not clear to me what are inputs are provided to the algorithm.  2. Please state the context and motivation.  Is this a practical problem you have encountered?  If so, what is the motivation? Is this a problem you encountered in some text?  If so, can you provide a reference?

Comment: 3. What criteria should we use for evaluating proposed algorithms?  What approaches have you already tried, and why have you rejected them?  If you haven't tried anything yet, I think it's premature to ask here.  Instead, you should try some standard optimization algorithms and see if they work acceptably or not, and use that to identify your requirements formulate a more specific question.  4. Please [edit] your question based on this feedback, so it contains all relevant information and reads well for someone who encounters this post for the first time.